# How to group meshes of a grid in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I'm working with geopandas, to simplify the problem, i have a geodataframe that could contains a lot of rows. These rows represent squares projected on the ground in epsg:4326 projection and could represent a grid of a particular area.

All the squares have the same size, i would like to group them 4 by 4 or 9 by 9 depending on a particular input value.

Here an example :

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd

a0 = shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0]).buffer(0.5, cap_style = 'square')
a1 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=1)
a2 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=2)
a3 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=3)
a4 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=4)


b0 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, yoff=1)
b1 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=1)
b2 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=2)
b3 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=3)
b4 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=4)

c0 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, yoff=1)
c1 = shapely.affinity.translate(c0, xoff=1)
c2 = shapely.affinity.translate(c0, xoff=2)
c3 = shapely.affinity.translate(c0, xoff=3)

liste_geo = [a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, c0, c1, c2, c3]
column = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'column' : column, 'row' : row, 'geometry' : liste_geo}, 
                       crs = 'epsg:4326', 
                       index = range(len(liste_geo)))

gdf.plot(facecolor = 'none')
```

[image]

My grid is represented by the gdf variable, i got squares with a particular size. I would like to group the 4 squares in red if my input variable is 2. In this example i would get a geodataframe with 7 new squares. If my input variable is 3 i would get a gdf of 2 new squares, the 2 on the right side would be lost.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you very much.

I made a first version of a function resolving this issue but it is way too long to compute with large gdf (~ 100k rows)

Here is the code

```
def define_spot_grid(gdf_base_grid, size_base, size_swath):
    """
    gdf_base_grid : our initial grid
    size_base     : size of the initial square
    size_swath    : size of our bigger square
    """

    rapport = size_swath/size_base
    unique_column = gdf_base_grid['column'].unique()
    unique_row = gdf_base_grid['row'].unique()
    liste_bigger_spot = []
    for k, v in gdf_base_grid.sort_values(by = ['row', 'column']).iterrows():
        # actually for every square i have a row and column information
        current_row, current_column = v['row'], v['column']
        bound_row, bound_column = v['row'] + rapport - 1, v['column'] + rapport - 1
        spot_bl = gdf_base_grid[(gdf_base_grid['row'] == current_row) & (gdf_base_grid['column'] == current_column)]
        spot_tl = gdf_base_grid[(gdf_base_grid['row'] == bound_row) & (gdf_base_grid['column'] == current_column)]
        spot_tr = gdf_base_grid[(gdf_base_grid['row'] == bound_row) & (gdf_base_grid['column'] == bound_column)]
        spot_br = gdf_base_grid[(gdf_base_grid['row'] == current_row) & (gdf_base_grid['column'] == bound_column)]
        # checking if all these squares exist
        if (not spot_bl.empty) and (not spot_tl.empty) and (not spot_tr.empty) and (not spot_br.empty):
            point_bl = spot_bl.unary_union.centroid
            point_tl = spot_tl.unary_union.centroid
            point_tr = spot_tr.unary_union.centroid
            point_br = spot_br.unary_union.centroid
            # we define a spot with 4 points
            bigger_spot = shapely.geometry.Polygon([point_bl, point_tl, point_tr, point_br])
            gdf_bigger_spot = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : bigger_spot}, crs = 'epsg:4326', index = [0])
            # we check how many spot our bigger spot intersects using a spatial join
            sjoin = gpd.sjoin(gdf_bigger_spot, gdf_base_grid, how = 'right', predicate = 'intersects').dropna()
            # example : if rapport = 3 we need to get 9 squares, if it is less we do not keep
            if len(sjoin) == rapport**2:
                liste_bigger_spot.append(sjoin.unary_union)
    gdf_bigger = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : liste_bigger_spot}, crs = 'epsg:4326', index = range(len(liste_bigger_spot)))
    return gdf_bigger
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the function you tried?

Comment: Yes i'm going to modified the post and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping over large dataframes in python tends to be slow. If spatial operations like sjoin are involved in each loop this effect will often become worse.

So, if possible, such loops should be avoided if performance is important.

The following code snippet illustrates how you can implement the same logic, without using a general loop:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd


def define_spot_grid(gdf_base_grid, size_base, size_swath):
    # First create gdf with all possible bigger spots, covering the bounds of
    # gdf_base_grid.
    # Remark: because we want to find all possible bigger spots with the number of small
    # spots asked, the bigger spots will overlap. 
    bounds = gdf_base_grid.total_bounds
    bigger_spots = []
    for xmin in np.arange(bounds[0], bounds[2], size_base):
        for ymin in np.arange(bounds[1], bounds[3], size_base):
            bigger_spots.append(
                shapely.geometry.box(xmin, ymin, xmin + size_swath, ymin + size_swath)
            )
    bigger_spots_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=bigger_spots, crs=gdf_base_grid.crs)

    # Check for each bigger spot how many small spots intersect with it. Join with
    # centroids of base grid to avoid spots that only touch being counted.
    base_grid_centroid_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=gdf_base_grid.centroid, crs=gdf_base_grid.crs
    )
    sjoin_gdf = bigger_spots_gdf.sjoin(
        base_grid_centroid_gdf, how="inner", predicate="intersects"
    )
    number_small_in_bigger_df = sjoin_gdf[["index_right"]].groupby(level=0).count()

    # Only keep bigger spots with the minimum needed number small ones in them.
    minimum = (size_swath/size_base) ** 2
    indices_to_keep = number_small_in_bigger_df[
        number_small_in_bigger_df.index_right >= minimum
    ].index.tolist()

    return bigger_spots_gdf.loc[indices_to_keep]

# Init parameters
size_base = 1

# Create base grid
a0 = shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0]).buffer(size_base / 2, cap_style="square")
a1 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=1)
a2 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=2)
a3 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=3)
a4 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, xoff=4)

b0 = shapely.affinity.translate(a0, yoff=1)
b1 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=1)
b2 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=2)
b3 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=3)
b4 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, xoff=4)

c0 = shapely.affinity.translate(b0, yoff=1)
c1 = shapely.affinity.translate(c0, xoff=1)
c2 = shapely.affinity.translate(c0, xoff=2)
c3 = shapely.affinity.translate(c0, xoff=3)

liste_geo = [a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, c0, c1, c2, c3]
column = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

gdf_base_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {"column": column, "row": row, "geometry": liste_geo},
    crs="epsg:4326",
    index=range(len(liste_geo)),
)

# Calculate for swath size * 2
size_swath = size_base * 2
bigger_gdf = define_spot_grid(gdf_base_grid, size_base, size_swath)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
gdf_base_grid.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none")
bigger_gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red", linewidth=2)
plt.show()

# Calculate for swath size * 3
size_swath = size_base * 3
bigger_gdf = define_spot_grid(gdf_base_grid, size_base, size_swath)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
gdf_base_grid.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none")
bigger_gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red", linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Result for size_swath = size_base * 2:

[image]

Result for size_swath = size_base * 3:

[image]